# how to setup glut/freeglut in codeblocks?

Tags: c, mingw, codeblocks, glut, freeglut

i'm new to all of this but i cant figure out where to put the lib and dll files in its proper place and i keep getting error messages such as down below

[this is the example of the error message on the right side of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvH3O.png)

i tried putting the lib files in C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib and the .dll files in C:\Windows\System32 and set the 'Other linker options' as:

-lopengl32
-lfreeglut
-lglu32

yet if i run the code, that i borrowed in the internet,in C language like in below, the error message appears

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>
#define KEY_ESC 27 /* GLUT doesn't supply this */

int fullscreen = 0;
int mouseDown = 0;

float xrot = 100.0f;
float yrot = -100.0f;

float xdiff = 100.0f;
float ydiff = 100.0f;

float tra_x = 0.0f;
float tra_y = 0.0f;
float tra_z = 0.0f;


float grow_shrink = 70.0f;
float resize_f = 1.0f;

void drawBox()
{


    glTranslatef(tra_x, tra_y, tra_z);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);



    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    // FRONT
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f( 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
    glVertex3f( 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    // BACK
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f( 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex3f( 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);

    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    // LEFT
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
    // RIGHT
    glVertex3f( 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex3f( 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f( 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f( 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);

    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    // TOP
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glVertex3f( 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f( 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    // BOTTOM
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex3f( 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex3f( 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
    glEnd();
}

int init(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.93f, 0.93f, 0.93f, 0.0f);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);

    return 1;
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluLookAt(
    0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    glRotatef(xrot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(yrot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    drawBox();

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void resize(int w, int h)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    gluPerspective(grow_shrink, resize_f * w / h, resize_f, 100 * resize_f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void idle(void)
{
    if (!mouseDown)
    {
        xrot += 0.3f;
        yrot += 0.4f;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}


void mySpecialFunction(int key, int x, int y)
{
    //if (key == GLUT_KEY_F1)
    //{
        printf("U -----------> rotate clockwise\n");
        printf("Y -----------> rotate counter clockwise\n");
        printf("W or w ------> Up\n");
        printf("S or s -----> Down\n");
        printf("D or d ------> Right\n");
        printf("A or a ------> Left\n");
        printf("Z or z ------> Shrink\n");
        printf("X or x ------> Grow\n");
        printf("Escape Key ---> exit the program\n\n");
    //}
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch(key)
    {
        case 27 :
            exit(1);
            break;



        case 'w':
        case 'W':
            tra_x += 0.1f;
            break;
        case 's':
        case 'S':
            tra_x -= 0.1f;
            break;
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            tra_z -= 0.1f;
            break;
        case 'd':
        case 'D':
            tra_z += 0.1f;
            break;
        case 'u':
        case 'U':
            xrot += 1.0f;
            yrot += 1.0f;
            xdiff += 1.0f;
            ydiff += 1.0f;
            break;

        case 'y':
        case 'Y':
            xrot -= 1.0f;
            yrot -= 1.0f;
            xdiff += 1.0f;
            ydiff += 1.0f;
            break;

        case 'h':
        case 'H':
            mySpecialFunction(key, x, y);
            break;
        case 'Z':
        case 'z':
            grow_shrink--;
            resize(500, 500);

            break;
        case 'X':
        case 'x':
            grow_shrink++;
            resize(500, 500);

            break;

    }


    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void specialKeyboard(int key, int x, int y)
{
    if (key == GLUT_KEY_F1)
    {
        fullscreen = !fullscreen;

        if (fullscreen)
            glutFullScreen();
        else
        {
            glutReshapeWindow(500, 500);
            glutPositionWindow(50, 50);
        }
    }
}

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        mouseDown = 1;

        xdiff = x - yrot;
        ydiff = -y + xrot;
    }
    else
        mouseDown = 0;
}

void mouseMotion(int x, int y)
{
    if (mouseDown)
    {
        yrot = x - xdiff;
        xrot = y + ydiff;

        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);

    glutCreateWindow("13 - Solid Shapes");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutSpecialFunc(specialKeyboard);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMotionFunc(mouseMotion);
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    //glutIdleFunc(idle);

    if (!init())
        return 1;

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)